# Changing colors of polygon based on numbers in separate Excel sheet using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

I have a shapefile and a separate excel Sheet.

I want this shapefile to interact with the excel sheet. I have assigned numbers associated with colors on this sheet, what I would like to do is have the shape color change with the numbers in the excel sheet.

I believe this is something I can accomplish in ArcGIS 10 ModelBuilder but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: what is the relationship between the features in your shapefile to the rows in your spreadsheet?  Is there a matching field?

Comment: there is a matching field, but the matching field is a name

Comment: By numbers do you mean RGB values or something else?

Comment: The numbers in the spread sheet are 1-5. Not RGB. The numbers are used in criminality statistics. For Example: Chicago has an extremely high crime rate, so the number assigned to the excel sheet is 5. In Belleville, Ill, the crime is low so the number assigned is 1.  The excel sheet has the information I need to assign areas colors.

Comment: @PolyGeo sounds more like a symbolise by attribute value through an excel join

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to improve your question with those additional details.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly different way of doing this, but you can do this with the [ArcGIS Maps for Office add-in](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/maps-for-office/).

I downloaded some crime stats and made a map out of it very quickly:
[image]